# Call NSLog from CocoaTouch Library

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, debugging, static-libraries, nslog

I am attempting to package a piece of an existing iPhone application as a static library. Parts of the library are not working correctly when I include the library from a test application, and I would like to debug my library.

I sprinkled a few NSLog calls throughout my library code and recompiled. However, when I call into the library from my test application, none of the log messages are displayed.

Are calls to NSLog suppressed when in a static library? If not, any guesses as to what I'm doing wrong. Are there better ways to debug a static library?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have more than one copy of the library? Maybe you are linking to the wrong version.

Comment: No, I ensured I just have one (although I did run into that issue earlier).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my problem. NSLog calls work fine. I needed to clean my test application before recompiling. Apparently the static library was not getting reloaded.